# Show an ad on the page when it is seen on the 4th time

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to build an app in which an ad should be loaded on the page every time the user views the page four times. I am using ionic framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show some examples of what you have tried and how it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to readout the documentation given by ionic framework.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

You can use the combination of `ionViewDidEnter` and `ionViewDidLeave` to achieve the goal.

Comment: @junaid let me know if its not working.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you so much for your answer:)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this result is saving the number of times your activity/page/whatever is seen. Save the number of visualisations, so when this is 4 then show the ad and finally reset the counter to 0. It isn't language specific answer, but a simple/basic programming solution. Apply this whichever your programming language is.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on any view (like button) and opens the activity, then create an int variable count and add a counter to view click to check how many times you open the activity.
If counts are equals to 4 then visible the Ad's, otherwise hide it